# How do I put a frame around a color box?

Tags: latex

I want to put a thin frame around my color box to be able to display white.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}
    \crule[gray]{5cm}{5cm} \crule[white]{5cm}{5cm} \crule{5cm}{5cm}
\end{document}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}}}

\begin{document}
    \crule[gray]{5cm}{5cm} \crule[white]{5cm}{5cm} \crule{5cm}{5cm}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{%
  {%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\phantom{\rule{#2}{#3}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
    \crule[gray]{5cm}{5cm} \crule[white]{5cm}{5cm} \crule{5cm}{5cm}
\end{document}
```